# Connect websocket to mysql database

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, sql, json

I am working on django project, in which i have to continue refresh the notification counter to check if the notification_status=0, every few second.
For that, i implemented ajax.
But its consume more cpu to refresh every few second..
So i want to use websocket to check, if new data is entered and pass the sql query throught the websocket.. !!

So finally my question is.
How to implement websocket in django or python to pass the sql query and fetch the result..!!???

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stackoverflow! Please provide any source code for solutions that have already been attempted [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you try searching Google first? https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket+python+mysql or https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket+django+mysql so anny results sure there would be a tutorial

Comment: Yes but i dont find any sarisfied solution for that..!!